# mysqli prepared statement cannot read unicode

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Assume  `Adams’ Inn` `America’s Best Inn` stored in the db table `establishment`

I have to check  `Adams’ Inn` `America’s Best Inn` in a variable `$EstablishmentName`

```
$stmt = $sql->prepare("SELECT ID FROM `establishment` WHERE Name=? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$EstablishmentName);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
print $stmt->num_rows;
```

The problem is I can't find them.

**OUTPUT** `0`

**Note** enclosed `$EstablishmentName` with `mb_convert_string($EstablishmentName,'HTML-ENTITIES')` else you'll end up with error `Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='`

**UPDATE:** I use `set_charset('utf8')` for the client side; the table charset is utf8, and collation is `utf8_general_ci`. The text is encoded as what the original text is. I am using the following DB Manager: SQLyog and PHPMyAdmin.

**UPDATE #2:** I have attached the screenshot for you to look that I am telling the correct charset.

[image: screenshot_1]

I use `$sql->set_charset('utf-8');`

```
Array
(
    [BrandName] => America's Best Value Inn
    [try1] => 1
)

Array
(
    [BrandName] => Adams' Inn
    [try1] => 0
)

Array
(
    [BrandName] => Ambassador Inn and Suites
    [try1] => 1
)

Array
(
    [BrandName] => Amberley Suite Hotel
    [try1] => 1
)

Array
(
    [BrandName] => America's Best Value Inn
    [try1] => 0
)
```

**UPDATE #3** Ok, sorry. The column `Name` was `latin1_swedish_ci`.
I have updated the column `Name`:

```
ALTER TABLE establishment MODIFY NAME VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

This should work without the `mb_convert_string()` now.

Comment: so your db connection's charset is? your table's charset? you mention htmlentities... so is that `’` stored as an encoded entity? raw text? your question cannot be answered without more details.

Comment: Both text encoded as what the original text is. I have set_charset('utf8') for client side, table charset is utf8, and collation is utf8_general_ci.

Comment: @MarcB do you have any thoughts about why this is happening?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**This solved the problem:**

```
iconv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', $EstablishmentName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put

```
mysqli_set_charset($db_connection, 'utf8');
```

after your database connection.

**Example**

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "xxxxx","database");
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
```

Answer (score -1):

The only thing I could tell that I see many confusions here

- prepared statements are irrelevant here, as they implements only method of data substitution, but do not alter the data itself. You will have the same result adding value into database directly.
- mb_convert_string cannot cause Illegal mix of collations error as this error is triggered by internal internal encodings conflict, not by the data format.
- there is no code to proof that stored value is equal to one used to check

Assuming you can get `Adams’ Inn America’s Best Inn` value based on id, let me suggest you to retrieve it, and then compare manually. var_dump() them. If you still cannot see the difference - urlencode() them first

Comment: I have updated the question. The column name was set to `latin1_swedish_ci` and I fixed it but still having the problem.