# MySQL: curve apostrophe ’ return none on WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the following data in tab-delimiter file (a txt or csv file).

```
Adams’ Inn  
Ambassador Inn a
Amberley Suite 
America’s Best Inn
Amber's Inn
```

I have a PHP script that will read those data to insert into the database. But, before they inserted the script will check them if they are already existed.

```
$stmt = $sql->prepare("SELECT ID,Name FROM `establishment` WHERE Name=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$Name);
$stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows==0){
    // do insert query
}
else{
    $stmt->bind_result($ID,$Name);
    $stmt->fetch();
    print "$ID:$Name already exist"';
}
```

**NOTE:** Assume that the `establishment` table has already the following data. I have the structure and data given below:

```
/*Table structure for table `establishment` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `establishment`;

CREATE TABLE `establishment` (
  `ID` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*Data for the table `establishment` */

insert  into `establishment`(`ID`,`Name`) values (1,'Ambassador Inn   '),(2,'Adams’ Inn'),(3,'Amberley Suite'),(4,'Amber\'s Inn'),(5,'America’s Best Inn  ');
```

Now, the script executed fine without an error but the problem is that the curve apostrophe`’`  cannot be search.

**So, any idea why this is happening on curve apostrophe`’`?**

**Another note:** When manually put it in a variable **`$Name = "Adams’ Inn"`** it works fine.

Comment: have you used `$stmt->bind_param("s",addslashes($Name));`. Try with it.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar The whole point of parameterized queries is that you don't have to do that.

Comment: @tc. Totally agreed :). I think if we can try with it and may be solve the problem.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar The purpose I use prepared statement is I don't want to modify text storing to db. Anyway, I tried each magic and did not resolve. You can try your own.

Comment: Do you both want the code to try?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14908446/285587

Comment: @YourCommonSense that's look similar but it is really different. I already solved that problem.

Comment: Downvoted though no one can solve this problem. That's funny. Who downvoted this question is crazy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This solved the problem.**

```
<?php
    function utf8_fopen_read($fileName) { 
        $fc = iconv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', file_get_contents($fileName)); 
        $handle=fopen("php://memory", "rw"); 
        fwrite($handle, $fc); 
        fseek($handle, 0); 
        return $handle; 
    } 
?>
```

**Demo:**

```
<?php
    ini_set('default_charset','utf-8');
    header('content-type: text/plain');
    $sql = new mysqli('localhost','root','','test');
    $sql->set_charset('utf8');

    $rows = array();

    $fh = utf8_fopen_read("sample.txt"); 
    while (($data = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, ",")) !== false) { 
        foreach ($data as $value) { 
           $rows[] = $value;
        } 
    }       

    foreach($rows as $row){     
        $row  = trim($row);
        $Name = $row;

        print "$Name\r\n";  
    }

    print "-----------------\r\n";

    foreach($rows as $row){     
        $Name  = trim($row);

        $stmt = $sql->prepare("SELECT ID,Name FROM `establishment` WHERE Name=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$Name);
        $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows==0){
            // do insert query
        }
        else{
            $stmt->bind_result($ID,$Name);
            $stmt->fetch();
            print "$ID:$Name already exist\r\n";
        }
    }
  ?>
```

**Save as sample.txt (tab-delimiter file):**

```
Adams’ Inn  
Ambassador Inn a
Amberley Suite 
America’s Best Inn
Amber's Inn
```

Answer (score 1):

That's most likely encoding problem.
Either proper encoding is not set or some of your apostrophes got encoded manually.

Make sure that your table have `utf8` encoding on them
make sure you're calling

```
$db->set_charset('utf8')
```

after connect.
(after doing that write NEW apostrother to database and try to read it back)

Make sure your code doesn't perform useless encoding like htmlspecialchars or so:

- select your problematic value from database, then `urlencode()` it
- read it's counterpart from CSV value and `urlencode()` it
- compare the results

Comment: I have $sql->set_charset('utf8'); and the db too, from table to columns all they are utf8. I don't need urlencode since the data is coming from a txt/csv file. **Note:** from my question, when I manually set it to a variable a single data, it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

The curved apostrophe is an abomination of Microsoft.  This link explains how to convert them back to single quotes as they should be:
http://www.toao.net/48-replacing-smart-quotes-and-em-dashes-in-mysql